# unexpected back slash added to char variables with read_xlsx

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

So I had this peculiar problem after importing an excel sheet with 'datetime' column as character (eg. "2018/1/5 17:12:26")

[image: excel sheet]

using `read_xlsx('filepath')`. It works well with numeric values in the first two columns, but adds some additional characters to the column 3

[image: datatime]

variable (eg.`"\"2018/1/5 17:12:26\""` ). I am running a R 3.6.3 on Mac.

[image: system version here]

Does anyone know what's happening here? I didn't specified any other args though.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: May be there is a double quote in the 3rd column.  Aftre reading the data, you can do `licks %>% mutate(datetime = ymd_hms(datetime))`

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: From the looks of your images (actual data notwithstanding), Excel kept the quotes when it read in to your spreadsheet, so it has literal quotes around the date. The backslash in `"\"...\""` is normal in that it is showing quotation marks in a string that is surrounded by quotation marks. This is normal for a string with embedded quotes. In this case, something else is wrong: why does Excel put quotes around the timestamp to begin with? I've never seen that or had it work within Excel, so that's incorrect entry or import (in Excel). `licks$datetime <- gsub('"', '', licks$datetime)` fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the dataset, we can convert the 'datetime' to `Datetime` class with `lubridate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
licks <- licks %>% 
             mutate(datetime = ymd_hms(datetime))
```

---

It seems that there are some double quotes, which would be automatically removed with `ymd_hms`

```
ymd_hms('"2018/1/5 17:25:36"')
#[1] "2018-01-05 17:25:36 UTC"
```